# Destroying $_SERVER session?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, twitter, http-authentication

Okay so I'm not using any session variables, rather my code looks like this:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Enter your Twitter username and password:"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Please enter your Twitter username and password to view your followers.';
    exit();
}

$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
```

So, my question is, how can I destroy this login session when the user wants to sign out of their (in this case) twitter login credentials?

Comment: same question, same answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/http-authentication-logout-via-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you can do is to send another 401 header. The browser will usually "forget" the old value, pop up another user/pass input dialog and if users then press the "abort" button they are "logged out".
Two drawbacks:

- The "abort the login to logout" dialog  may surprise users a bit
- "usually" means: better not depend on it.

edit: And has already been answered, [HTTP authentication logout via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/http-authentication-logout-via-php)

Comment: This plus other possible methods are mentioned in the comments of the php manual. However like you said they are not guaranteed to work.
Link: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#76511

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to destroy an http authentication login server side. This is one of the biggest disadvantages of this form of login.