# How to logout when using .htaccess (and .htpasswd) authentication?

Tags: php, authentication, .htaccess, logout, .htpasswd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP authentication logout via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/http-authentication-logout-via-php)

Hi

I have a some functionality on my website protected using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`. 
When users attempt to access this, they get prompt to enter details. They enter their details and get in and can see stuff etc. All works fine.

My question is how do I create a `logout` functionality for this type of authentication. I know that they can close the browser window to "Logout". But this is not ideal. What would you suggest to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Has been asked before, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/http-authentication-logout-via-php

Comment: There isn't any kind of implementation without writing few lines to remove the session, or reset the headers. Try the straight forward approach. http://blog.acpmasquerade.com/2011/09/basic-http-authentication-straight.html#more

Comment: This one is not really a duplicate of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/http-authentication-logout-via-php ; the latter is not very specific about the authentification method, whereas the question here is about .htaccess and .htpasswd. In this sense this question here has a more precise wording.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Browsers usually don't support this, see [How do I log out?](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html)

> Since browsers first started
>   implementing basic authentication,
>   website administrators have wanted to
>   know how to let the user log out.
>   Since the browser caches the username
>   and password with the authentication
>   realm, as described earlier in this
>   tutorial, this is not a function of
>   the server configuration, but is a
>   question of getting the browser to
>   forget the credential information, so
>   that the next time the resource is
>   requested, the username and password
>   must be supplied again. There are
>   numerous situations in which this is
>   desirable, such as when using a
>   browser in a public location, and not
>   wishing to leave the browser logged
>   in, so that the next person can get
>   into your bank account.
>
> However, although this is perhaps the
>   most frequently asked question about
>   basic authentication, thus far none of
>   the major browser manufacturers have
>   seen this as being a desirable feature
>   to put into their products.
>
> **Consequently, the answer to this
>   question is, you can't. Sorry.**

There are browser extensions that allow you to clear the HTTP authentication for a site.
For Firefox the **[WebDeveloper](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)**  extension (which is one of my favourtie extensions anyway) offers this feature.
The menu for this is `Miscellaneous/Clear Private Data/HTTP Authentication`.

Comment: Firefox's default way of logging out of HTTP auth is available under "Tools" > "Clear Recent History...", as checkbox "Active Logins". This is neither intuitive nor does it allow you to only log out of one domain, you allways log out of every page.

Answer (score 35):

**Tested on firefox and chrome**. What you can do is send the user to http://logout:logout@example.com. This will replace their current username/password with logout/logout (it could be any invalid user/pass combination) and since they now have the wrong username/password, they will have to login again to access the site.

On opera this does not work, because you can have several usernames/passwords at the same time. It didn't work on IE either, because IE does not appear to support http://username:password@example.com URLs.

Comment: According to RFC 3986 (URI: Generic Syntax) section 3.2.1. (User Information) the use of `user:password@host` is deprecated. Using only `http://logout@yourserver.example.com/` isn't and should work in most cases.

Comment: this worked for me in chrome today, great stuff, thanks guys!

Comment: I confirm that this works in Chrome as well, thank a lot!

Comment: On Chrome 45, after logging out and logging in again, prompt is always popping-up...

Comment: Do note that this solution is not necessarily future-proof. A browser can - at any time - decide to start supporting multiple active logins or some other feature that breaks this.

Comment: This looks like working but once you refresh the page you might login again with previous account. I have seen that in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue several years ago. It is incredibly frustrating to discover there is a problem everyone is having and no one seems to want to solve in a general way.

As noted in [Inadequate Logout functionality in HTTP Authentication](http://computerstuff.jdarx.info/content/inadequate-logout-functionality-http-authentication) I think the answer is to change the RFC to allow timeouts and support a log out button. The author's additional suggestion that the server be able to send a "log out" header would actually eliminate the need for *any* client user agent support since websites could simply include a link on a web page to a URL that returns the necessary response code and/or header to invalidate the current session.

Answer (score 1):

It IS kind of possible to log out. You should implement logout page, which will return HTTP 401, until the user enter BAD login information, and then redirect somewhere else. Browser remembers the latest login information accepted, and therefore overrides correct login.

But this is kinda unusable, cos it needs user's cooperation.