# Apache forced logout?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am running a LAMP server and when users access the server homepage I am using the Apache basic authentication to log them in. Is there a way to force the user to logout (or be logged out)?  I tried the mod_session & mod_auth_form to no avail. The page I'm using is a mix of php/html. I am self taught on all of my programming skills so I lack the depth to get a workable solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **you can't.**

Check these sources:

> **No correct way exists**, not even one that's consistent across browsers.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/449914/3960852

---

> Consequently, the answer to this question is, **you can't**. Sorry.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1163876/3960852

---

However, there are certain ways for CERTAIN browsers. If you plan to only support a specific browser, which is a valid course of action, there are hackish ways of accomplishing it.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36176917/3960852

---

However, the jury is out. If you want to log out HTTP authenticated users **with extensive browser support,** you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at these suggestions I worked out a solution, albeit not a clean and elegant one. I followed the idea of the protected folder with an htaccess file. When the user clicks on my logout link they get a JavaScript alert to click on cancel when prompted for username and password. In my htaccess file I put in an override for a custom 401 error document which I then made as a logout page. 
The user clicks cancel and gets redirected to the page telling them the logout was successful. I put a link on that page to log back in as well. With Firefox so far the user has always had to submit credentials to log back in. Dirty but it works.