# how to log out with http basic Authorization?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, backbone.js, web

I'm now doing a project that use Backbone.JS,for this case ,the server-side should be RESTful,but,how should I implicit the Authorization?I used to do this with session,And if i use http-basic Authorization,how to log out?
thank you for helping my question(my English is just so so :D);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163122/http-basic-authentication-log-out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/http-authentication-logout-via-php

Comment: Duplicate of [How to log out user from web site using BASIC authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507). It would be good to consolidate the info into a single place.