# Javascript clean cache to clear Basic Auth credentials

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication

I am trying to make a logout with basic authentication. I am wondering, if there is any possibility to clean client's browser cache via JavaScript? Are there any alternative ways to calling logout webservice?

Comment: Basic Authentication managed by the browser? If so, there is no logout (I think not even with help from the server).

Comment: This may help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript

Comment: Maybe the hack mentioned here (which can be triggered from JS) works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163122/http-basic-authentication-log-out?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with JavaScript for security reasons, logout normally would just delete whatever it has created, which is normal behavior.