# Resetting password-protection on Apache web directory

Tags: apache, password-protection

I have a password-protected Apache web directory I'm testing.  When I first access the directory, it requires that I login in.  However, on subsequent tries it let's me right in, even after I clear my browser cache- how do I get it to force a login again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser stores the credentials and sends them along with every request - usually, for the duration of the current session.

Closing the browser and re-opening it makes it usually forget the credentials.

Forcing the browser to forget credentials (i.e. logging out) is tricky. See [HTTP authentication logout via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/http-authentication-logout-via-php) for some approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I've found:

Using Firefox 4 on Mac,

1. Go to 'Tools' > 'Clear Recent History...' > 'Active Logins'
2. Refresh the page (You don't have to close the window)