# Can I programmatically log a user out of .htaccess authorization?

Tags: apache, php, .htaccess

I'm using Apache "Auth" security to limit access to my web site (via commands in the .htaccess file, an .htpasswd file, etc).

Is there a way to de-authorize a user via my PHP script, effectively giving them a way to log out?

Comment: And the answer is: Not really. This question has been asked before, put "trac" into your search.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I asked on the unix stackexchange site, and didn't see it there, but I'll search for 'trac'.

Comment: There is one ticket in the trac trac that is about that which contains a lot of insighful information. At least one SO question links that, but I don't remember the link out of my head.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/http-authentication-logout-via-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
// this PHP will cause a logout event, and give the login prompt again

$AuthName='WHAT-EVER'; // must match AuthName in .htaccess.
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
header('Content-type: text/html');
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="'.$AuthName.'"');

// now redirect them when they click cancel
// should be to a page with no password required.
// use an HTML meta redirect instead of HTTP 
// so it runs after the auth is cancelled.
?>
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;../'></head></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

With that type of authentication, the username and password are actually send by the browser on every subsequent request.  As there's no way to tell a browser "hey, stop sending those", there is no way to do what you're trying to do.

(If, however, you had a PHP script involved that was handling part of the authentication, you could set a session variable for flagging to ignore the valid authentication and pretend the user is logged out.)

However, in terms of a *good* solution, there is not one.  The user will stay logged in until his or her browser decides to stop sending the headers (usually when the browser is closed).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#99348