# How to De-Authenticate a Windows Auth user with PHP

Tags: php, windows, iis-7, windows-authentication

If a user logged in to my site with windows auth, how do I log the person out so that they will have to be authenticated again? (this is with IIS)

For example the user logs in like this:

[image: auth]

Then the `$_SERVER` variable contains:

```
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 172.34.567.891
[REMOTE_HOST] => 172.34.567.891
[REMOTE_PORT] => 44601
[REMOTE_USER] => DOMAIN\username
```

And the user is not asked again for his username or password with windows auth unless the computer is restarted, or he uses a different browser.

How do I **force** the user to be authenticated again with PHP?

---

### Update:

I found a way to do this, but it only works in chrome (all other browsers just throw a 401 unauthorized, even if the login is correct):

My code:

`logout.php`

```
    //clear session
    //then:
    $user = isset($_SESSION['userName']);
    $userNotSet = (!$user || (is_array($user) && count($user) == 0));
    
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION['401']) && $userNotSet) {
        $_SESSION['401'] = true;
        $realm = 'mysite';
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$realm.
           '",qop="auth",nonce="'.uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($realm).'"');
        exit;
    }
    elseif($userNotSet) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
        list($domain, $user) = explode("\\", $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']);
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
    }
    else    {
        header('Location: '.WEBROOT.INDEX);
    }
    exit;
```

Why doesn't this work in any other browser aside from Chrome? Is there a cross-browser solution?

Comment: I assume the underlying principles are similar to standard HTTP authentication. It's not possible to log-out programmatically then. See [HTTP authentication logout via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/449788/367456).

Comment: Why don't you get PHP to communicate directly with Active Directory or whatever is handling Windows Auth. and relay it to the user? That's what I did when I had a similar problem. This way PHP had total control over the user's session.

Comment: @NullUserException what did you do?

Comment: I worked in a company where all user authentication was handled by Active Directory, so you had one username and password combination for everything. I wrote an internal web application in PHP which used their AD for authentication, but the sessions themselves were managed by PHP.

Comment: @NullUserException is there any code you can show me, or is it all proprietary?

Comment: The communications with AD were largely handled by this opensource project: http://adldap.sourceforge.net/

Comment: AD is just LDAP with extras, and most LDAP libraries can handle it.

Comment: Which route through the if/elseif/else is the non-Chrome browser taking?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP with HTTP Basic Auth, then there are two `$_SERVER` variables you need to be using and testing: `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` & `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`.

To force the display of the browser's HTTP basic auth login dialog, you send a 401 header. It doesn't matter if the user is logged in or not, you can send the 401 header at any time to force the user to re-enter their credentials.

This code shows the basics:

```
<?php

// If the force_login request variable exists, then we want the user to
// re-enter their login details.
if (isset($_GET['force_login']) && $_GET['force_login'] == 1) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="realm"'); 
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized'); 
    exit;
}

// Login process
if (!$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) {
    // The browser has not supplied $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], so we need 
    // the user to log in 
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="realm"'); 
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized'); 
    exit;

} else {
    // Test that the username/password combination are correct
    $expectedUsername = 'test';
    $expectedPassword = '1234';
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $expectedUsername 
            && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $expectedPassword ) { 
        // not valid username/password - try again!
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="realm"'); 
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized'); 
        exit;
    }
} 
// End login process


// The user is logged in here. we can display the page content
echo '<a href="?force_login=1">Force login</a>';
```

(As a side note, if you're using HTTP basic auth, ensure you're using SSL too!)

Comment: +1 for the note about using SSL with HTTP basic auth. (HTTP basic auth sends the user name and password in clear text).

Comment: @RobAllen -- I am using IIS Windows Based Authentication, will it still work then?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure. I've always managed authentication within my app. I think you don't need to worry about the PHP_AUTH Stuff and can simply send the 401.