# How to logout when using header function in php?

Tags: php, mysql, http-authentication

I try to login via header function (HTTP authentication). I take username and password and #check it in MySQL database.  It woks! but in log out I have a problem!

How can I delete active login that make via function below? (I must say I can logout if I #delete active sessions in my browser!). should I unset `php_auth_user` server variable?

```
<?php
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
?>
```

Comment: There is a equal Question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/http-authentication-logout-via-php

Comment: Take a look at here -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php