# How to logout user for basic HTTP authentication

Tags: authentication, browser, basic-authentication

Is there a solution to logout a user (make a browser clear its cached credentials and ask user to login credential once again) for basic HTTP authentication?

I've already looked through the following questions:

- [logout with basic authentication without closing webbrowser like banking sites will display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131767/)
- [HTTP authentication logout via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449788/)

Comment: Duplicate of [How to log out user from web site using BASIC authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507). It would be good to consolidate the info into a single place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's not very smooth.

You have a special script URL (eg `/logout`; like a login script it must be in the root of the webapp to ensure the auth gets set to the right path), which, instead of requiring a valid username/password to proceed, requires an invalid one.

So the logged-in user hits `/logout`, sending valid credentials in the `Authorization` header. Your script responds `401`, and the browser pops up a username/password prompt. You tell the user to put false values in (or, in most browsers, just leaving it blank is OK too) and hit OK. This replaces the valid stored credentials with invalid ones. Your script then returns a ‘logged out’ page or a redirect back to the home page, and the user is no longer logged in.

(Care: Safari, sadly, passes every HTTP request without any credentials first, only trying again with stored credentials if it gets a `401` response. This means you shouldn't take a request with no `Authorization` header as being OK for the logout script; it must be present, even if with blank credentials in it. This unfortunate behaviour also means you can't provide a logged-in and not-logged-in version of the same page to Safari users under the same URL, and it makes Safari slow at browsing Basic-protected sites, since every page request has to happen twice.)

There is another way that is sometimes used: use JavaScript to send an `XMLHttpRequest` with a fake username/password combo (eg `xhr.open('GET', '/app', true, '_', '_')`). This has the non-standard side-effect of replacing the stored credentials in IE and Firefox (but not Opera; not sure about the others).

[Ugh. This is a pain. No wonder everyone uses cookies instead...]

Comment: @bobince, could you please explain the JavaScript solution a bit more. It is not working for me

Comment: In what format do I have to address the application (/app)?

Answer (score 6):

A solution proposed in an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11882603/348920) is to point the logout link to a URL that contains fake credentials e.g. http://log-me-out:fake-pwd@example.com/logout