# how to make a logout menu button for blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I made a blackberry app which authenticates the user when he logs in but, once you log in you can't log out.

I need a logout button for the blackberry menu button.

I'm using basic authentication in java.

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(encoded));
```

The encoded string is the "user:password"
I'm developing this app with the eclipse plugin.
Any ideas, tutorials or code?

Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer for [How to log out user from web site using BASIC authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication). Same principle applies to mobile apps as well.