# Auth and fatfree framework

Tags: fat-free-framework

I have been playing with Auth of fatfree using two routes login and logout. The first time I used login in a url the dialogue box came up asking for username and password. After typing in a username which exists in the table field 'user_name' and password in field 'user-pass' I got `true` for `$result` so web page displayed it works. Interestingly I have not got code `new Session();` anywhere yet when i then went to url `/logout` `echo $f3->get('SESSION.pass');` was correctly displayed suggesting Auth starts a session.

In my `/logout` route after   `echo $f3->get('SESSION.pass');`
I have `$f3->clear('SESSION');`.

Yet if I then flip back between `/login` url and logout url, the dialogue box no longer shows and logout still displays '1234' which is SESSION.pass. I would have thought that after going to `/logout` url the session would clear, so after  going back to `/login` url i though it would bring up the login dialogue box to login.

In a nutshell my question is "how do you logout of Auth"? The documentation doesn't seem to mention it.

```
$f3->route('GET    /login',
  function($f3)
  {
    $db = new \DB\SQL('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;      dbname=accra_names2','root','victoria');   
    $user = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db, 'users');

    $auth = new \Auth($user, array('id'=>'user_name', 'pw'=>'user_pass'));
    $result = $auth->basic(); // a network login prompt will display to authenticate the user 
    $f3->set('SESSION.pass','1234');

    if($result)
    //result true
    {
      echo "it works";
    }
  }
);

$f3->route('GET    /logout',
  function($f3)
  {
    echo "you want to log out ";
    echo $f3->get('SESSION.pass');
    $f3->clear('SESSION');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your question is "how to logout from HTTP basic auth".
There are several topics and answers about it here on SO, like this one [How to log out user from web site using BASIC authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication)
So if you want full control about the login/logoff mechanisms you go probably better with own html forms instead of the browsers basic login box.

Comment: cheers ikkez i switched to using web web form with a POST to route and using ideas here:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/f3-framework/4Yl-bZxTMVE  im happy with the way it works only one question i tried this in a route: function beforeRoute($f3) { } instead of normal $f3->route('GET /somepage',
    function($f3) {} it didn't work - either i mis-understood it or typed it wrong

Comment: No the beforeroute is a hook called from any controller class you have setup a route to. So if you have $f3->route('GET /somepage','Controller/Page'); then beforeroute for this route goes into your page class at controller/page.php

Comment: ok got auth working and a no frills forum here: http://www.accra-guesthouse.com/forumTopics will have a read up on the fatfree docs