# HTTPs logout Browser-base authentication (basic authentication via browser)

Tags: javascript, php, web

I am stuck at logout function (JavaScript) to log user out of a browser-based authentication.

I can use http://wronguser:wrongpassword@domain.com/ to logout. But it can work with http only.

How to make it works with HTTPs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/233551/1207049

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to log out user from web site using BASIC authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication)

Comment: Hi, as I told before, it can work with http but cannot work with https.