# How to logout in Python Bottle?

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

I have the following test snippet:

```
def check(username, password):
    if username == "b" and password == "password":
        return True
    return False

@route('/logout')
@route('/logout', method="POST")
def logout():
# template with a logout button
# this does redirect successfully, but this shouldn't happen 
    redirect('/after-login')


@route('/after-login')
@auth_basic(check)
def after_login():
    return "hello"

@route('/login')
@route('/login', method="POST")
def login():
    return template("views/login/login_page")
    username = post_get('username')
    password = post_get('password')
```

I'm attempting to log out of the system, but I haven't been able to find any resources on how to do this. Basically, I tried dir(response) and dir(request) and haven't found any functions that appears to set the session off (mostly attempting to reset cookies), unless I close the browser.

Comment: Btw, you can collapse your `@route` calls into one. `@route('/login', method=['GET', 'POST'])`

Answer (score 0):

Issued the same problem. Well, The decision I found in docs and used is `response.delete_cookie('<cookiename>')`
So every time I enter the page with setting any cookies, first I delete all possibble to change cookies.

Comment: Won't work in this case. The OP's code uses Basic Auth, not cookies.

Comment: anyway it doesn't worked for me as described. Every time i deleted all the cookies this way all set_cookie wasn't working any longer in every metod for particular routes. 
So the only thing worked was deleting all the cookies that wasn't re-set

Answer (score 0):

You want to log out of HTTP Basic Auth, which is not really what it was designed for. But there [does seem to be a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233551/593047): return an HTTP 401.

```
from bottle import abort

@route('/logout', method=["GET", "POST"])
def logout():
    abort(401, "You're no longer logged in")
```

Does this work?