# symfony2 LDAP Logout Action

Tags: php, symfony, ldap, symfony-2.8

After a few hours I got a working LDAP-Login, based on the 'new' symfony2 ldap component from November 11, 2015 ([see here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-ldap-component)). Also I followed the docs about the [log out](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#logging-out). 
But everytime I request on that logout function, nothing seems to happen. The user is still logged in.

This is my code:

*app/config/security.yml*

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:   ^/
            stateless: true
            http_basic_ldap:
                service: service.key
                dn_string: "{username}@example.tld"
            logout:
            path: /logout
```

*Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml*

```
vendor_bundlename_logout:
    path: /logout
```

Depending on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233551/4214381) answere my question is: 
Do I have to manage the logout by myself with incorret login credentials? Or did I missconfigured the logout aspect in the security.yml?