# http-auth 'logout' works, but then login fails

Tags: php, security, http-authentication

Since there is no real way to log out of a site using http-auth, I am using a kludge.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://log:out@example.com" />
```

This works, the http-auth login screen pops up and they are logged out.  However since there is a dummy user and password included in the URL, attempting to log in again without refreshing the page doesn't work.

I tried using the real username in the URL and leaving the password (which I don't know) blank, but that doesn't help.

Is there a way around this.  So that if someone logs out using my (or another) method, they can log straight back in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log out user from web site using BASIC authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Not really.  I know how to log out.  That isn't the issue.  This is about once logged out, how to have the borwser in a state to be able to login again.

Comment: Did you read the complete accepted answer and the comments? They are touching that issue as well. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/492926/2453432) also gave some alternatives (which should enable you to login again).