# HTTP Basic Auth logout

Tags: javascript, apache, html

My server is running Apache and I used .htaccess for my basic auth. However, I want my users be able to cancel the auth (log out) with a button. Is it possible and how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic Auth is not designed to manage log-out. If you would like to do it then you need to do the following:

1) Add a logout button to your page.

2) When user click on the log-out button send a blank username/password to the same URL as in case of normal log-in.

3) In the response you send back a “You have successfully logged out” page.

The original credentionals will be will overwriten with the empty (wrong) one.

Hope that it helps you.

Comment: It's already been answered almost 10 years ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication

Answer (score 2):

First of all, HTTP does not provide logout: [HTTP/1.1. spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.6)

But! You can redirect user to: `http://newuser@www.example.com/`

Comment: It's already been answered almost 10 years ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication

Comment: Brilliant! I just edited the href of my existing Sign Out button to point to such an URL.

Comment: N.B. redirection technique no longer works for Chrome 65+