# How to sign out of mongo-express BasicAuth

Tags: mongodb, docker

[mongo-express for docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express/) comes with quick Basic Authentication environment variables -- `ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME` and `ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD`. Once those variables are set for a container it correctly requests basic authentication for web browser access.

My problem: Once authenticated, I could not find "log out" or "sign out" anywhere in the interface.

Are there ways of removing the authentication when done with the session?

Comment: delete session cookie

Comment: okay -- so no UI element in mongo_express for this, just edit cookies in your browser?

Comment: In your, not in mine =) You asked "Are there ways" - there are. I gave you one, but there might be other. Wait for answers or fork the project and add the UI you are missing. It's quite basic express app.

Comment: Absolutely -- not complaining, just making very sure I did not miss anything that already exists before considering rolling my own. Maybe based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32325848/7207622