# How to add deauthentication in ESP8266wifiserver

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I am setting up authentication in an esp8266WiFiServer and I managed to add authentication process. But The problem is I can't add logout/de-authentication in the code.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "your-ssid"
#define STAPSK  "your-password"
#endif

const char* ssid = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const char* www_username = "admin";
const char* www_password = "esp8266";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi Connect Failed! Rebooting...");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
  ArduinoOTA.begin();

  server.on("/", []() {
    if (!server.authenticate(www_username, www_password)) {
      return server.requestAuthentication();
    }
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "Login OK");
  });
  server.begin();

  Serial.print("Open http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/ in your browser to see it working");
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoOTA.handle();
  server.handleClient();
}
```

I am trying the code and works well. But I need a logout button. Any Idea how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Study https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I finally managed to complete the logout

Answer (score 0):

just add below for logout:

server.on("/logout",  {
server.send(401, "text/html", "logged out!");
});