# how to logout user from dash application with Basic-auth?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am new to Dash. I am developing an app in Dash which uses basic authentication (Dash-Auth) for login. I am providing predefined usernames and passwords to users. I keep track of logged user using their usernames. My question is, how to logout user from the application without closing the browser? I mean how to erase the user credentials so that when user try to login next time, user will be prompted with username and password again?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication