# How to authenticate every request with BASIC in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, basic-authentication

Now there is authentication only once when I open my browser. I want to authenticate each request without need to reopen the browser.
This is my configuration class. What can I add to configure function?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().csrf().disable().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("").password("{noop}").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log out user from web site using BASIC authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication)